# SQL - on which context do SELECT...FOR UPDATE and UPDATE work?

Tags: sql, transactions

I would like to have a question about data contexts on which do the transaction operate with different commands.

Are there any differences in SELECT...FOR UPDATE and UPDATE in terms of contexts of data?

What I mean by this: if I run the following transaction (pseudo-code):

```
begin transaction;
select user for update where id=1;
update user set name="TOM" where id=1;
commit;
```

What this actually does is that it locks the user in exclusive mode and so other transactions can't access it in any way, right?

When the transaction commits, the data is written and the lock is released.

But then what about these transactions:

**T1**

```
begin transaction;
select user for update where id=1;
update user set name="TOM" where id=1;
select user where id=1; //BREAKPOINT
commit;
```

and **T2:**

```
begin transaction;
update user set name="TOM" where id=1;
select user where id=1; //BREAKPOINT
commit;
```

I believe that SELECTs at the BREAKPOINTs will return the updated user. If that's so, why?

The UPDATE and SELECT...FOR UPDATE both lock the user in exclusive mode in the "real" table (table with the data committed from other transactions), while the actual content of the update (name="TOM") is visible only to the transaction manipulating it until the transaction is committed?

Does this mean that every transaction works in its own "context" which holds the changes made by its subsequent commands?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I believe that SELECT, UPDATE and SELECT...FOR UPDATE are standardized commands which are required to be implemented by all SQL databases...? So consider any of the major providers such as Postgres, SQL Server, MySQL,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case transactions cannot run simultaneously - first transaction, which would be run, will lock record with id = 1.

They do not have two their own states - only one transaction will work and it should see own changes

Comment: Yes, only one of the transactions can run at the time because they operate on the same lock. But how does the transaction see its changes and why the other transactions can't see them? Does it operate on some sort of context which stores changes from all of its subsequent commands?

Comment: Yes, it stores changes of their own and can read it. Exact implementation depends from a database, but in simple you can imagine like this:
NAME      NAME_UNCOMMITTED_BY_TRANSACTION
SHARP    VIOLET

Other transactions read committed state, and the transaction read the new state
Other transaction cannot update row, because it's locked - and you only one new state. For example if you have two updates of the same value in one transaction you don't need to save two states and commands - you need to save only one new state

Comment: Okay, thank you :) Though let me have one more question before I accept your answer. While the transaction is not yet committed, how does e.g. SELECT * from user; behave if run concurrently? I believe that it still includes the user even though it's locked?

Comment: Transaction have ACID principles - Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability. What you asking in this question is Isolation principle. Isolation - is expensive, that's why there are 4 levels of it - Read uncommitted, Read committed, Repeatable read, Serialyizable. What you are asking about differences beetween read uncommitted and other. read uncommitted transaction can see other changes while other levels - not seeing. So, by default database do not use read uncommitted level only if you ask (and if exists)

Comment: Usually, (it depends from the implementation of the database) for select you need shared lock which allows to read data (only committed) but transaction cannot apply changes until reading is over. And if implementation allows to read it until another transaction is in progress - other transactions will see current state